# Flutter SSO Okta Integration Example

Tags: flutter, dart, okta

I'm trying to convert my android and ios application to Flutter. In these core platform I've used OKTA authentication  using `WebView`. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37867131/7012285)  post helped me for android SAML SSO implementation.

I've gone-through OKTA documentation. I didn't see `Dart` and `Flutter` related stuff.

Any code examples appreciated - especially one showing Flutter implementation of generic SSO, if such a thing exists.

Comment: You might try Flutter AppAuth https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_appauth

Comment: @MattRaible thanks for comment. I want to show okta login page in Webview with  webviewClient . other dependencies not allowed here.

Comment: I'm fairly certain that won't work. I've tried many times to embed the Okta Sign-In widget in mobile apps and I've found it doesn't work.

Comment: I've already done same in [Android](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37867131/7012285) and Ios apps. now looking same for flutter. Flutter supporting web also right, might be some way is there.

Comment: Hi @GowsikRaja, could you please share do we have any solution available in flutter.

Comment: @SathishGadde I didn't checked yet. But I've done through Flutter  Platform channel using core platform code.

Comment: Could you please provide any sample code, if possible

Comment: Can you pls check this : https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/platform-channels

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [flutter_okta_sdk](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_okta_sdk) plugin. This implements SSO with Okta OIDC. The plugin only has support for Android and iOS though. Here's a [sample](https://github.com/marktefftech/flutter_okta_sample/tree/c76f80a8064b9ef6c64a28a086b2722bff289bf0) that you can try out. You can follow this [setup guide](https://github.com/sonikro/flutter-okta-sdk#flutter-okta-sdk) to get you started.