# Flutter SAML SSO OKTA null safety integration

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I need to implement SSO with Okta. I've found this [documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64032644/flutter-sso-okta-integration-example). But the package( flutter_okta_sdk) used here is not null safety.

How could I implement SSO okta in Flutter with null safety mode. Is there any other way to implement this? Need Help

Answer (score 0):

The question has been [asked and answered](https://github.com/sonikro/flutter-okta-sdk/issues/24):

> We don't have a timeline for that yet, but our repo is open to receive contributions. It would be awesome if you can help us on that.

So if you can do that, feel free to contribute.

Otherwise your options are to go back to before sound null safety with your own app or... wait more. Rock and a hard place really.

Comment: nvoigt, Yes, I've read these things. I need suggestion is there any alternatives by using that I could implement SSO Okta.